# can't backup to a NAS drive as offline schedule task

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, schedule

I have seen this problem issue discussed in several forums including this one, but could not find a solution.
On MS server 2003 I configured a Backup task, the target backup is on a NAS disc (Seagate BlackArmor NAS 110). The backup task is working well as a scheduled task or by a direct command, when I am logged on. It is not working when the user is offline (in this case - Administrator).

I already tried the following actions: 1) addressing to the target as network drive (Y:location..), 2)Using UNC instead, 3) making the drive a domain member (the NAS admin S/W allows to define itself as a domain member)
The result log message for 1 and 2 is: "The operation was not performed because the specified media cannot be found."
The result log message for 3 is empty file.
The schedule task "RUN" command is:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntbackup.exe backup "@C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\NTBackup\data\de-board.bks" /a /d "Set created 2/14/2010 at 5:10 PM" /v:yes /r:no /rs:no /hc:off /m incremental /j "de-board" /l:s /f "\10.0.0.8\public\Backups\IBMServer\de-board.bkf"
10.0.0.8 is the static IP of the NAS.
"Run only if logged on" is NOT marked.
Password of the administrator user is set.

It is obvious that there is no access to the NAS when the user is logged-out.
Do you have any idea how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a service account rather than a user account.

From technet:

> A service account is often described
>   as any account that does not
>   correspond to an actual person. These
>   are often built-in accounts that
>   services use to access resources they
>   need to perform their activities.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875826.aspx

Comment: Thanks.
As far as could see, this article is about security issues of accounts. The Administrator account that I am using for backup might risk my system but I do not see how it can limit access to a NAS drive.